# Spatial query using my SQL

Tags: mysql, polygon, spatial-query

I am writing from two varChar formatted columns named 'lattitude' and 'longitude' to a Point formatted column named 'coordinate' using the statement below.

```
"UPDATE table_name SET coordinate = PointFromText(CONCAT('POINT(',table_name.longitude,' ',table_name.lattitude,')'))"
```

I attempting to do a spatial query on the coordinate column using the following statement.

```
SELECT id , coordinate FROM table_name WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('Polygon(-126.728566 49.226434, -123.652395 23.586457,-56.679738 23.908252,-53.076223 55.243002)'), coordinate)
```

According to this [tool](http://www.keene.edu/campus/maps/tool/) the polygon in my query covers the entire U.S. I know there are points in my table that fall in the U.S. but I am still not getting any results (note I'm getting a null result not an error). Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATE. Below is an updated attempt at executing my query per the suggestion below.

```
SET @g1 = GeomFromText('Polygon((23.586457 -123.652395,23.908252 -56.679738,55.243002 -53.076223,55.243002 -53.076223,23.586457 -123.652395))');

SELECT id , coordinate FROM table_name WHERE MBRContains(@g1, coordinate)
```

Comment: Do you not have to close polygon?

Comment: I tried adding the first coordinate again at the and and still got the same result.

Comment: did you try setting simple data for testing into table_name, like the data, used here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/relations-on-geometry-mbr.html. To check, that everything works as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id , coordinate FROM table_name WHERE MBRContains(GeomFromText('Polygon((-126.728566 49.226434, -123.652395 23.586457,-56.679738 23.908252,-53.076223 55.243002, -126.728566 49.226434))'), coordinate)
```

This should work. The problem is that Polygon coordinates should be in double parenthesis. It has something to do about interior rings ([polygons](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/polygon-property-functions.html)). Plus as David noticed You need to close polygon.

PS: I noticed You use longitude as X and latitude as Y when this should be other way around. X are horizontal and Y vertical.

Comment: longitude is X and latitude is Y

Comment: The X is the coordinate on the horizontal axis so you draw a vertical line from the point to the X-axis to find the X coordinate and the other way around with Y.

Answer (score 4):

As you are dealing with coordinates you have the lat lng coodinates crossed.

I created a Google Map using the coordinates below(reversing the order of your coordinates in the Question.

```
new google.maps.LatLng(49.226434,-126.728566),
new google.maps.LatLng(23.586457,-123.652395),
new google.maps.LatLng(23.908252,-56.679738),
new google.maps.LatLng(55.243002,-53.076223)
```

[image: Polygon]

Google Maps does not require polygon to be closed.

According to  [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/relations-on-geometry-mbr.html) MBRs require the polygon to be closed.

```
mysql> SET @g1 = GeomFromText('Polygon((0 0,0 3,3 3,3 0,0 0))');
```

**EDIT**
In answer to comment Have you the correct CHARSET ?

Typical spatial table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_name` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `coordinate` geometry NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Ensure `CHARSET=utf8;`

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your suggestion. I have attempted to implemented (demonstrated in the edit above) but I'm still not getting any results. I wonder if I'm not writing to my coordinate column properly. I should probably mention that when I look at my coordinate column in phpMyAdmin, it looks like a bunch of encoded characters ( e.x. ������/=�[J@) i.e. not human readable. Not sure if this is normal.